# FFMPEG&PHP: Videos modified by FFMPEG are not played in Firefox

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg

I use this code to cut a section of a video

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$url." -ss ".$start." -to ".$end." -c copy ".$result);
```

This code works very well, and the result is played in Google Chrome and IE, but the firefix reports

> no video with supported mime type found.

The `$url` which is the source video, is played in all browsers.

The video format is `.mp4` and the player is html5 player of the browser. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the mime type specified in the <video> tag? The error has nothing to do with the ffmpeg but with the player on FF

Comment: does the original .mp4 video play correctly in Firefox? can you share a live example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

mp4 is not supported by Firefox unless a 3rd party codec is present to handle the de-coding - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats - if you want to include Firefox as a target you should also provide an encoding that Firefox supports out of the box.

you can use the `canPlayType` functionality to see if you need a fallback...

```
var obj = document.createElement('video');
if (obj.canPlayType('video/mp4') == 'probably') {
    // you are okay with mp4
} else {
    // try with video/webm or some other supported format
}
```

you should also make sure the response includes the correct content type (mime type) via the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
```

Comment: The source MP4 can be played within Firefox, and the OP is simply streamcopying a portion, so it's the same codec and format.

Comment: @Mulvya, The videos are played via CPanel of my site. I mean when I click on their file and then select the `view` from the menu, they are played in the browser but some of them are not playing via the `<video>` tag of my site.